# How do you avoid InvalidArgumentException in Selenium controlled via phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to use `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase` to write some e2e testing but it keeps throwing the following exception:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Element not found.
```

Obviously I checked the page `signup_page.php` and all the HTML elements are there and the behaviour of the form being sent is also working (it prints a "success" message when it is submitted). It clearly cannot find any of the element on the page but for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Here's the code of the test:

```
$this->url("signup_page.php");
$this->byName("username")->value(self::USERNAME);
$this->byName("email")->value(self::EMAIL);
$this->byName("password")->value(self::PASSWORD);
$this->byTag("form")->submit();
$this->assertRegExp("/success/", $this->byTag("body")->text());
```

I can see the browser being directed to the page but then it suddenly dies as the exceptions is thrown.

And here's the php page just in case:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
   </head>
   <body>

      <form action="signup.php" method="get" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">

         <fieldset>

            <legend>Signup</legend>

            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

            <label for="email">email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

            <label for="password">password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="signup" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" />

         </fieldset>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

phpunit-selenium is not fully compatible with selenium 3 + geckodriver + firefox.

See https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/issues/427 for code change improving compatibility (and solving the specific "InvalidArgumentException: Element not found" problem)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I replaced the driver with chrome instead of FF

```
...
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->setBrowser('chrome');
    $this->setBrowserUrl($this->host);
}
...
```